# Timestamp in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timestamp, nsdate

I have date, for example: `2012-02-07 14:09:46.109950` and I need timestamp as `1328623786.568740`, there is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-02-07 14:09:46.109950"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
[dateFormat release];

NSLog(@"%f", interval);
```

But now, I have such result `1328623786.110000`, .110000 - is rounded. Please help me to get not rounded result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

function `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();`

or `CFDateGetTimeIntervalSinceDate(CFDateRef theDate, CFDateRef otherDate);`

or `CFDateGetAbsoluteTime(CFDateRef theDate);`

**UPDATE**: your value automatically rounded here 
`NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-02-07 14:09:46.109950"];`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

result:

```
2012-02-07 14:09:46.110000
```